# Android Notifications Not Stacking API 24

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to stack notifications from an app, such that they appear grouped as apps such as gmail. The following code is generating a new notification in the notification bar each time.

The android documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html talks about notification channel groups that work with `setGroup`. but NotificationChannelGroup is only as of API 26. The feature works on my phone (API 24) in other apps so there must be way to make the notifications stack. does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

UPDATE:
I found it, turns out in order to group messages into a stack using `setGroup("MY SUPER DUPER GROUP")` you first have to send a notification that serves as the container for the other ones which has `setGroupSummary(true)`. and use an ID of zero for that notification `nmng.notify("CROWMAIL", 0, sum)` so that if the previous summary has been removed it will create a new one, but if one already exists it will have no effect.

updated working code:

```
NotificationManagerCompat nmng = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
Message[] msgs = folder.getMessagesByUID(a.data.uidnext, uidnext-1);
Notification sum = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
        .setGroupSummary(true)
        .setGroup("CROWMAIL")
        .build();
nmng.notify("CROWMAIL", 0, sum);
for(int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(msgs[i].getFrom()[0].toString())
            .setContentText(msgs[i].getSubject())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
            .setGroupSummary(false)
            .setGroup("CROWMAIL")
            .build();
    nmng.notify("CROWMAIL", previous+i, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what your use case is e.g have separate notifications for different events, or have them bundled. For the latter, Android provides this functionality particularly for API's less than 26 by `InboxStyle` notifications.

Note that `InboxStyle` notifications are used in cases where a single notification is preferable such as individual messages from a single person, or a list representation of single-line text items.

Here is an example from the docs

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
        .setContentText("Events received");
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[6];
// Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
...
// Moves events into the expanded layout
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {
    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
// Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
...
// Issue the notification here.
```

Comment: inboxstyle is nice, but i'm going for the convention of several notifications grouped into a list, but the list is expandable and each notification in that list is individually clickable

Comment: Okay, I see, let me edit my answer to incorporate this.